# Proper way to use different views for each version using django rest framework QueryParameterVersioning

Tags: django-rest-framework, versioning

We are using version parameter from url, for example, urls.py:

```
/api/<str:version>/entities
```

The problem is we need to navigate to different views depending on version parameter. Is there any solution without using regex url path names? What solution have you used in such case? Thanks in advance.